# Is it possible to run programs nodejs in bash?

Tags: bash, javascript, bash-scripting, node.js

My question is simple : I have a program written in nodejs and want to run it in an infinite loop in the language bash, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

while true
do
   node <myapp>
done
```

you can also use it as a one liner while true; do; node ; done;

Answer (score 0):

You can run your app in the background like so

```
$ node app.js &
```

If you are looking to keep a running node process, though, I would look into the [forever package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever).

```
$ sudo npm install forever -g
$ cd /path/to/your/project
$ forever start app.js
```

Comment: Yes, I know  But for the project I'm doing i needed to run it  with bash

Comment: @D4IVT3 - Updated answer. I really wouldn't use a while-true loop because it will lock up your computer infinitely creating node processes.

Comment: @D4IVT3 - Also, you have node installed and therefore npm, so there is no reason not to use forever to start and monitor your node process.